# how does java work in ubuntu?

Tags: java

Is java the same in ubuntu as with a text editor like note pad? if so do I just write the script and save as java in ubuntu? 
running ubuntu server 14 on 32 bit pc no other os running on that pc.

Very new to all this and would like a little insight! 
thanks

Comment: A simple google search will clear lot of doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Java is cross-platform so you can run same Windows code on Ubuntu. Difference is that if you have a file path specified in the code, you may want to change it. Additionally if you write to a file, remember that text files in Windows end with \n\r , while on any *nix it's just \n. If you have some Windows specific packages you wish to import , that may be an issue. Otherwise , you are 99.9 percent safe

Comment: Ok thank you. So I can write script in either? Just wondering if it would be easier to write it on the server, or windows and add jdk, or do I have to add jdk in either? Just trying to find out what way is easier.

Comment: You need jdk and jre in either one. Windows and Ubuntu don't come with java bu default. As for writing, anywhere will do, but on server you might test things . . .or break things.....